# Django URLField doesn't accept hostname-only URLs

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm currently using Django with Docker. I have main dispatcher Django project, and several other microservices that are running on different Docker containers.

When I start up a new microservice, I want to add new Django model which has `URLField` pointing that microservice. But `URLField` doesn't accept such URLs, e.g. http://foo-service/ and it's because of [these code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/46b3e3ffdc25b5a42762df20e536401fc512c5f3/django/core/validators.py#L74).

Of course I could define custom validator or custom field that inherits `URLField`, but shouldn't `URLField` accept those URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunaly Django `URLField` doesn't accept URLs as `http://foo-service/`. You have actually answered your own question by posting the source code for `URLValidator`.

If you want to have a field that supports URLs outside of the scope supported by `URLField`, you have to create your own validator. Because there are many people who faced this problem before, there is already a third-party Django app:

https://github.com/edoburu/django-any-urlfield

Eventually it might save you some time.

Comment: Ok, so this could be Django's later improvement! I'm gonna make my own validator right now